# Choose specific value to show in a textbox from a SQL View

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database

I am pretty new to programming in general so I am going to bagger this question in a thousand ways at least and I am sorry ahead of item. I have a view of a couple tables I created in a SQL database. They have foreign key relationships and a couple one to many tables. I have an employee table and a phone number table that are linked.

All employees have at least 1 number some employees have 2 or more numbers listed and I want to be able to choose which number of the few to show in a textbox or even in a couple text boxes. If I do textbox.text = employee.PhoneNumber (subsonic) then it only gives me the first number. Can someone point me to a guide or explain to me how I would choose which of the said values I would like to show in that textbox?

Thank you very much for any assistance you can give.

p.s. When I test the veiw in sql I get the same employee listed multiple times because of the different numbers so I know the data is there I just dont know how to access the other 2 phone numbers in the list.

Comment: It would probably help if you posted the code of what you are doing now and we could help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have zero experience with subsonic but it does look strange that you can access a non scalar value like this (employee to phone number is a 1-n or m-n relation so employee objects should NOT have a scalar field containing a phone number, but a collection of 0 or more phone number objects) if your employee objects have a scalar phone number object i would recommend to check the relation

//edit

so your VIEW contains something like this:

```
employee + phone  
John Doe | 123  
John Doe | 456  
Jane Doe | 789
```

lets say that result is an enumeration of some type T containing the values as properties or fields with the given names ...

so you have

```
IEnumerable< T > data; // initialized somewhere else
IEnumerable< IGrouping<WhateverTypeEmployeeIs,T>> tmp = from x in data group x by x.employee;
var employees = from x in tmp select new { employee = x.Key, phoneNumbers = x.Select(y => y.phone).ToArray() };
```

employees will contain an IEnumerable< > of a new anonymous type with 2 properties:
employee - containing your employee
phoneNumbers - containing an array of phone numbers

Comment: You actually completely lost me but I guess I will try to explain better. I have a couple employees which all have at least one phone number. Some have 2 or more phone numbers in the phonenumber table. When I test the employee view in sql I get the same employee listed 3 times because of the 3 differences in the data. In asp.net I can load employee data into the text boxes but I want to load each of the linked numbers to different text boxes for that one employee.

Comment: ah ... my approach was a bit too object oriented ... in terms of LINQ you will probably want to group your result by the employee and itterate the groupings elements for the phone numbers of that employee ... i'll edit my post in a sec...

Comment: Thank you I will have to try this code out. Still need to learn it I am truly just off the presses with asp.net and programming in general. Thank you for the help.